# Json post para PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

Olá,

Preciso pegar os dados que estão sendo passados via Ajax POST. Porém do lado do PHP não estou conseguindo pegar os parâmetros passados.

Meu código **Jquery**

```
onSave: function(data, name) {
        pixie.http().post('images/gravar_imagem.php', [{"name": name, "data": data}]).subscribe(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    },
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
     $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
     $request = json_decode($postdata);
     $name = $request->name;
     $data = $request->data;
     
     echo $name; 
?>
```

aparece o seguinte erro:

> error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at
> JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.u
>
> text: "
> ↵**Notice**:  Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in **C:\xampp\htdocs\pixie\images\gravar_imagem.php** on line **17**

Comment: O erro está dentro do servidor, quando há um erro no servidor, a resposta vem com tags html '<' quando há um erro php irá adicionar tag com a mensagem de erro. Portanto, seu json contém as tags html e se torna inválido devido a tags inesperadas.

Comment: Tu envia o json pro php então tu não deveria dar um json_decode em vez de encode?

Comment: @fajuchem erro meu eu escrevi errado.. editei a pergunta.

Comment: @Tfm irei verificar se realmente está com tags html meu jason.

Comment: O que te retorna console.log(response)?

Comment: Ele não chega a entrar no console.log(responde)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postando para mostrar como resolvi a duvida que tinha:

No método **OnSave**

```
onSave: function(data, name) {
        /*pixie.http().post('images/gravar_imagem.php', [{"name": name, "data": data}]).subscribe(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
  });*/

  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'images/gravar_imagem.php',
     data: { data: data , name: name},
   }).success(function(response) {
      alert(response);
   });
  },
```